# Shortcut for creating simple dialogs in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

Android Newbie here! I spent all yesterday trying to implement a simple dialog in my android app. I realised there is no easy way out. I mean all i just wanted to show to user is a simple choice between importing a video into the app from the gallery or recording a live video. My Parent UI is already consisting of two fragments in a split-pane style(Details on the left, gridview on the right). Now i want to show the options for importing a video as a dialog. Turns out i have to create another fragment(DialogFragment), give the fragment a UI(ListView), create UI for the list items, create adapters for my list, override getView method for my adapter with custom logic. is there no shortcut to this? While this might make me sound lazy (which i'm not btw cos i love coding), what if i want to create 4 additional dialogs, do i have to do this everytime? is there no easy way out?

btw I'm targeting SDK 11 to 19 devices.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)?

You could use this to build your dialog and then set your click handlers on `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton` methods if you only want two options.

It was added at API level 1.

Comment: Yes...My bad! I should have looked at the documentation for  AlertDialog.Builder properly before posting this question. Good thing i can set a custom Views. thanks ;)